# Migrating a git repo with its merge request

Tags: git

I have a git repo in server1 and I want to migrate it to a GitLab server, when I say migration I mean all branches, tags and merge requests.
I already tried mirroring, it worked well except for merge requests. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link [How to Migrate](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer/)

I use this, and it work for me. If you cant do it, please notice me.

Comment: Actually I'm using GitLab, So the process is different.